# Added textview code crashed the application in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, textview, progress-bar

I am working on a homework project that requires to have a textview counter along with an existing progress bar.  I added the textview code to java file and main.xml.  When I run it in the emulator I get "The application xxx has stopped unexpectedly" message.  I have not been able to figure out the cause.  Here is my code:
(Code indentation is not entirely proper.  I will strive to make it so)
Source file:

```
package com.mypackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyButtonActivity extends Activity {
   static final int PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;
   Button button;
   ProgressThread progressThread;
   ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   TextView Int;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Int = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Int);

    // Setup the button that starts the progress dialog
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Show dialog managed by this activity
            showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        }
    }); 
}

// Callback for creating dialogs that are managed (saved and restored) 
// for you by the activity. 
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
    case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyButtonActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        // Create and start the handler
        progressThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
        progressThread.start();

        return progressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

// Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and update 
// the progress
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");
        progressDialog.setProgress(total);
        Int.setText(String.valueOf(total));

        if (total >= 100){
            dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            progressThread.setState(ProgressThread.STATE_DONE);
        }
    }
};

/** Nested class that performs progress calculations (counting) */
private class ProgressThread extends Thread {
    Handler mHandler;
    final static int STATE_DONE = 0;
    final static int STATE_RUNNING = 1;
    int mState;
    int total;

    ProgressThread(Handler h) {
        mHandler = h;
    }

    public void run() {
        mState = STATE_RUNNING;   
        total = 0;
        while (mState == STATE_RUNNING) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Thread Interrupted");
            }
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("total", total);
            msg.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            total++;
        }
    }

    /* sets the current state for the thread,
     * used to stop the thread */
    public void setState(int state) {
        mState = state;
    }

}
```

I only added a few lines to existing code (including a textview to main.xml).  So is it more involved than simply adding textview code to implement the textview counter?  Given that it is one of first projects in my intro level course, I think simply adding a textview should satisfy the requirement.  Please enlighten.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check logcat and post the error that it throws here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it worked for me! Did you try to:

1. Under Eclipse bar Project->Clean Project
2. Right click on your project Android Tools->Fix Project Properties

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  Problem solved:  Logcat stated I did not have layout_width specified for textview.